Unable to locate Nvidia Nsight or fix the broken package or stop it
So I am using ubuntu 22.04 and I had space issues so had to clean up and may have deleted the .deb for this, this nvdia package wont fix, and i dont know how to remove this completely. I tried downloading the original .deb file but access is blocked on the nvdia site.
This is the result of when i run sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-cccl-12-5 cuda-command-line-tools-12-5 cuda-crt-12-5 cuda-cudart-12-5
  cuda-cudart-dev-12-5 cuda-cuobjdump-12-5 cuda-cupti-12-5 cuda-cupti-dev-12-5
  cuda-cuxxfilt-12-5 cuda-documentation-12-5 cuda-driver-dev-12-5 cuda-gdb-12-5
  cuda-libraries-12-5 cuda-libraries-dev-12-5 cuda-nsight-12-5
  cuda-nsight-compute-12-5 cuda-nsight-systems-12-5 cuda-nvcc-12-5 cuda-nvdisasm-12-5
  cuda-nvml-dev-12-5 cuda-nvprof-12-5 cuda-nvprune-12-5 cuda-nvrtc-12-5
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-5 cuda-nvtx-12-5 cuda-nvvm-12-5 cuda-nvvp-12-5 cuda-opencl-12-5
  cuda-opencl-dev-12-5 cuda-profiler-api-12-5 cuda-sanitizer-12-5
  cuda-toolkit-12-5-config-common cuda-toolkit-12-config-common
  cuda-toolkit-config-common cuda-tools-12-5 cuda-visual-tools-12-5 gds-tools-12-5 gyp
  libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libc-ares2 libcublas-12-5 libcublas-dev-12-5 libcufft-12-5
  libcufft-dev-12-5 libcufile-12-5 libcufile-dev-12-5 libcurand-12-5
  libcurand-dev-12-5 libcusolver-12-5 libcusolver-dev-12-5 libcusparse-12-5
  libcusparse-dev-12-5 libjs-events libjs-highlight.js libjs-inherits
  libjs-is-typedarray libjs-psl libjs-source-map libjs-sprintf-js
  libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libnode-dev libnode72 libnpp-12-5 libnpp-dev-12-5
  libnvfatbin-12-5 libnvfatbin-dev-12-5 libnvjitlink-12-5 libnvjitlink-dev-12-5
  libnvjpeg-12-5 libnvjpeg-dev-12-5 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libuv1-dev
  libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss nsight-compute-2024.2.0 nsight-systems-2024.2.3
  python3-proton-vpn-session
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nsight-systems-2024.2.3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nsight-systems-2024.2.3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
32 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/342 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-5-local  nsight-systems-2024.2.3 2024.2.3.38-242334140272v0 [342 MB]
Err:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-5-local  nsight-systems-2024.2.3 2024.2.3.38-242334140272v0
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-5-local/./nsight-systems-2024.2.3_2024.2.3.38-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-5-local/./nsight-systems-2024.2.3_2024.2.3.38-1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-5-local/./nsight-systems-2024.2.3_2024.2.3.38-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Then sudo apt autoremove brings me back to this -
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-nsight-systems-12-5 : Depends: nsight-systems-2024.2.3 (>= 2024.2.3.38) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Im unable to locate these files too. Im a new linux user, so navigating is still new.
Thanks

"had to delete a bunch of files"? Which files? How did you delete them? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
